# Getting shape's frame a in binary image matlab

Tags: matlab

I have the following binary image:
[image]

What I'm trying receive eventually is this:
[image]
Does anyone have an idea for solving it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can experiment with using the [Canny edge detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector) along with non-maximum suppression. These [lecture slides](http://www.cs.illinois.edu/class/sp12/cs543/lectures/Lecture%2006%20-%20Edge%20Detection%20-%20Vision_Spring2012.pdf "Edge Detection, UIUC CS 543") may also be useful for you starting from around page 29.

Comment: The several `edge` detectors in matlab as well.  Just look up the `edge` function.  Paired with `bwmorph` you should be able to work something out.  Otherwise you might need to create your own filter and use a combination of `imdilate` and `imerode` with particularly designed structuring elements.

Comment: Given the defects in your image, I would focus on finding a robust way to fill the characters, and then either use an edge detector or morphological operations to find the boundary.  Applying edge detection on your corrupted image will probably pick up the edges of the defects inside the characters, which you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, we assume the letters are white (1) on a black background (0). (i.e. the outside of the image is black)

The following matlab script worked using combinations of erosion, dilation, filling, and AND/OR/NOT logic operations:

```
     %This script assumes the input image is a binary bitmap image
     %Otherwise use: 
     %BW = logical(BW); after loading grayscale image with BW = imread(filename); 

     BW = imread('img.bmp'); %read in the image
     figure
     imshow(BW) %show original image

     %for the outside edges
     BW2 = imfill(BW, 'holes'); %fill holes in letters
     BW3 = imerode(BW2, strel('disk',1));
     BW4 = BW2 & (~BW3); %outside boundary of letters (8 connected)
     figure
     imshow(BW4) %show outside edges

     %for the inside edges
     BW2 = imerode(BW3, strel('disk',1)); %erode filled letters again
     BW3 = ~(BW & BW2);  %logical AND operation of original image and doubly eroded filled letter image
     BW2 = ~imfill(BW3,1); %fill image with white (1), starting at 1,1 leaves
     BW3 = imfill(BW2, 'holes'); %fill inner holes
     BW2 = BW3 & (~BW2); %logical operation to isolate inner holes
     BW3 = imdilate(BW2,strel('disk',1))-BW2; %boundary of inner edges

     BW2 = BW3 | BW4; %logical OR operation to obtain inside and outside edges
     figure
     imshow(BW2) %final image
```